# Django forms: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm a newer to Python, and I am having a problem with Django's forms:

```
  args="[('job_201404181748_1712666','job_201404181748_1712666')]"
  jobid = forms.ChoiceField(choices=args)
```

This raised `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`. If I replace `args` with a string, then it works ok:

```
 jobid = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('job_201404181748_1712666','job_201404181748_1712666')])
```

I don't know why. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try this :- jobid = forms.ChoiceField(choices=eval(args))

Comment: yes,you're right  @TanveerAlam

Comment: the args is build by the for loop. @TanveerAlam

Comment: Here 'eval' function just evaluates your string 'args' to List.

Comment: While I am sure it could work, I would advise against arbitrary use of the `eval` function. It is seen as quick&dirty and could have some nasty side effect, especially in web applications dealing with user input. I never had to resort to using `eval`, and I am confident that @lanyun could write his code in a way that avoids it as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `args` without the surrounding quotes. By surrounding it with quotes, you make `args` into a string. The ChoiceField expect a list of choices.

in short, make line 33 look like:

```
 args=[('job_201404181748_1712666','job_201404181748_1712666')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the quotes

```
args=[('job_201404181748_1712666','job_201404181748_1712666')]
```